# "object is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have a node.js application that is using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to call methods one after the other.  For some reason when I try to go to the second tier of the waterfall, my application throws the following error:

> TypeError: object is not a function

I have the following code which is coffeescript (i can get javascript if anyone wants it):

```
async.waterfall([
    (callback) =>
        console.log 'call getSurveyTitle'
        @getSurveyTitle (surveyTitle) =>
            fileName = 'Results_' + surveyTitle + '_' + dateString + '.csv'
            filePath = path.resolve process.env.PWD, 'static', @tempDir, fileName
            csv.to(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
            callback(null, null)
    ,
    (callback) =>
        @createHeaderRow (headerRow) =>
            headerText = _.map headerRow, (row) =>
                row.text
            csv.write headerText
            console.log 'before' #gets here and then throws error
            callback(null,headerRow)
    ,
    (headerRow, callback) =>
        console.log 'after'
        @createRows headerRow, (callback) =>
            callback(null,null)
    ], (err, result) =>
        console.log "waterfall done!"
    )
```

Im fairly new to node and async, so I have a feeling I am just overlooking something obvious.  Can anyone see what I am doing that could cause this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `waterfall`, any `callback` arguments after the 1st `error` will be passed to the next task, including `null`s:

```
async.waterfall([
    (callback) =>
        callback(null, null, null)
    ,
    (callback) =>
        console.log callback  # null
        console.log arguments # { 0: null, 1: null, 2: [Function], length: 3 }
])
```

If you don't want any values passed to the next task, just call `callback` with only the `error` argument:

```
callback(null)
```

Or set a name for the 1st argument so `callback` is 2nd:

```
(_, callback) =>
    @createHeaderRow (headerRow) =>
        # ...
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!  So is what is happening is that the second tier is receiving a null argument, when it should receive no argument at all?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Well, "*should*" is up to you. But, yeah, it's receiving a `null` argument that it's not currently expecting.